# Programa para renomear ficheiros

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou a tentar desenvolver um pequeno programa para renomear lotes de ficheiros (pdf, etc). Imaginem que o padrão é "1250_F1_001A_E01-001A00.pdf" e no final obteria "1250_F1001A00.pdf", Mantinha os primeiros 7 e os últimos 6 de qualquer ficheiro. O que está no meio seria eliminado.

O problema está em `fileName.LastIndexOf(3, 3));` dá erro constantemente.

O código que estou a tentar produzir é o seguinte:

```
namespace RenomeiaPdfs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string DIRECTORY_PATH = @"C:\Users\...\RENOMEIA";
            if (Directory.Exists(DIRECTORY_PATH))
            {
                string[] filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(DIRECTORY_PATH);
                foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
                {
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        // Get the file name
                        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                        // Get the file extension
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);

                        // Get the file name without the midle part
                        string fileTitle = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf(3, 3));
                        File.Move(filePath, DIRECTORY_PATH + @"\" + fileTitle + fileExtension);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do [João](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112798/jo%C3%A3o-martins), você deve tratar os casos onde o nome pode se repetir após a alteração (Erro "ficheiro já existe").

Como sugestão você pode criar uma lista com os novos nomes e sempre ao alterar, verificar se o nome do novo arquivo está na lista, se estiver, você não poderá usá-lo novamente. Pode usar o padrão do windows para esses casos: arquivo(1).pdf, arquivo(2).pdf etc.

**obs**: *item.Path* é o seu *filePath*

```
    //Lista que não aceita valores repetidos
            HashSet<string> novosNomes = new HashSet<string>();

            //Iterando pelos arquivos
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                if (File.Exists(item.Path))
                {
                    //Nome do arquivo
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item.Path);
                    //Extensão do arquivo
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(item.Path);
                    //Diretorio do arquivo
                    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(item.Path);

                    string fileTitle = $"{fileName.Substring(0, 7)}{fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 6, 6)}";

                    //Se o nome não for duplicado
                    if (novosNomes.Add($"{fileTitle}{fileExtension}"))
                    {
                        //Append do novo nome ao diretorio
                        var newPath = Path.Combine(path, $"{fileTitle}{fileExtension}");
                        File.Move(item.Path, newPath);
                    }
                    //Se o nome já existir na HashList
                    else
                    {
                        var novoNome = "";
                        //Variável para evitar nomes repetidos
                        int i = 1;

                        do
                        {
                            i++;
                            novoNome = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", fileTitle, $"({i})", fileExtension);
                        } while (!novosNomes.Add(novoNome));

                        //Append do novo nome ao diretorio
                        var newPath = Path.Combine(path, novoNome);
                        File.Move(item.Path, newPath);

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Obrigado Joabe Alexandre. Nunca existem nomes de ficheiros repetidos. Os padrões de nomes são sempre estes: 2000_F1_001_008G_E01-006G00.pdf / 2000_F1_001_008G_E01-007G00.pdf, etc e que deverão dar origem aos nomes: 2000_F1006G00.pdf/ 2000_F1007G00.pdf

Comment: Eu alterei o trecho do código para obter o nome sem a extensão (var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(item.Path)), visto que com a extensão deu erro de repetição pra mim. Já testou isso também?

Comment: O problema está em                         string fileTitle = $"{fileName.Substring(0, 27)}{fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 8, 10)}"; Se não remover os caracteres corretos, depois pode criar ficheiros com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Nesse trecho, a primeira subtring está obtendo o nome do arquivo completo (na questão pede-se os 7 primeiros dígitos) e ao final está obtendo uma string além do tamanho do texto. Não está claro o que você está buscando.

Comment: string fileTitle = $"{fileName.Substring(0, 7)}{fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 6, 7)}"; O problema está aqui. Pois não remove os caracteres corretos.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que isto resolverá o seu problema:

```
string fileTitle = $"{fileName.Substring(0, 7)}{fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 6, 6)}";
```

Se calhar será também melhor validar se a `string` tem tamanho suficiente para obter essa informação:

```
if (fileName.Length >= 7)
    // ...
```

Comment: Obrigado! Se eu tiver vários tipos de ficheiros na mesma pasta, surge o erro System.IO.IOException: 'Impossível criar um ficheiro quando esse ficheiro já existe.

Comment: Mas pretende sobrepor o ficheiro que já existe? Ou simplesmente passa para o próximo?

Comment: Pretendia renomear todos os ficheiros (existentes num dado dir) com esse padrão e carateres, de forma a reduzir o nome, mas mantendo sempre a extensão. Se forem todos do mesmo tipo, não há problema. Se forem de tipos diferentes, surge esse erro. Ainda não descobri o motivo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado a todos. Já encontrei a solução. A dificuldade estava em entender a Substring.

```
string fileTitle = $"{fileName.Substring(0, 7)}{fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 10, 10)}";
```